# Can the mkOr(Expr<BoolSort> ... t) fuction in the Z3 Java Api get a list as input?

Tags: java, z3, solver, smt

Unfortunately, I cannot post the entire code here, because i am programming (modelling) in a DSL that is build on top of Java. The question does not necessary require that though:

I am trying to create a longer Or-Expression like: p == 1 Or p==2 Or p==3 and so on.
I have a list of BoolExpr, which contains the list of those EQ-expressions (i.e. p==1, etc).

In python i could now just give this list of expressions to the mkOr method of the API and that was it. My code snippet below though complains that list is not a subtype of BoolExpr.

```
list<BoolExpr> eqExprList = new arraylist<BoolExpr>;

// populate this list with p==1, p==2 etc.

MyContext.mkOr(eqExrList); // this produces the error
```

So the question is basically, whether it should normally (in a real java) work like this or whether I am misunderstanding the API documentation: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classcom_1_1microsoft_1_1z3_1_1_context.html#aea714fc46f4c625ecc15397522099330

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but it has to be a regular array; not an `ArrayList`. So, you should first convert it to an array:

```java
import com.microsoft.z3.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Z3Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Context ctx = new Context();

      IntExpr x = ctx.mkIntConst("x");
      IntExpr y = ctx.mkIntConst("y");
      IntExpr z = ctx.mkIntConst("z");

      ArrayList<BoolExpr> eqExprList = new ArrayList<BoolExpr>();
      eqExprList.add(ctx.mkEq(x, y));
      eqExprList.add(ctx.mkEq(y, z));

      Solver s = ctx.mkSolver();
      s.add(ctx.mkOr(eqExprList.toArray(new BoolExpr[eqExprList.size()])));

      System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

This prints:

```
(declare-fun z () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)
(declare-fun x () Int)
(assert (or (= x y) (= y z)))
```

So the part you're missing is:

```java
ctx.mkOr(eqExprList.toArray(new BoolExpr[eqExprList.size()]))
```

which makes a regular array out of an `ArrayList`, which can then be fed to the `mkOr` function.

Comment: No problem. On stack-overflow, you indicate an answer has helped you by “accepting” it, i.e. by clicking the green check-mark next to it and upvoting it. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers